# C# Minesweeper - When cells with no mines nearby gets clicked

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm currently making a Minesweeper in C#. I've already done the basics (generating minefield, rules and ui) but I don't know how I should implement when the user clicks a cell and the cell has no mines nearby and clicks nearby cells with also no mines nearby, like this:

[image: Minefield before click]

And after click

[image: Minefield after click]

This is my current code on this:

```
if (MineField(x,y) == false) // If the clicked cell isn't a mine
{
    if (GetNeighbours(x,y) == 0) // GetNeighbours returns the amount of mines in the closest 8 cells
    {
        // To be honest, no idea...
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply the amount of mines in the neighbor tiles is not enough, you need to return an array of the tile references / coordinates, so you can call your Click() methods, or whatever you want to happen if the neighbor tiles are empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this, is to use recursive [Flood Fill algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill). Something like:

If cell(x,y) has no bomb:
1. If coordinates (x,y) didn't went beyond game board, and cell (x,y) wasn't marked as visited:

a) give cell (x,y) property visited to true (or mark it in any other way)
  b) if getNeighbours(x,y) > 0: print number of cell (x,y) 
  c) if getNeighbours(x,y) == 0: reveal cell (x,y) and call whole function responsible for revealing field for coordinates (x-1,y-1),(x-1, y), (x-1, y+1), (x, y+1), (x+1, y+1), (x+1, y), (x+1, y-1), (x, y-1).